# Month column in dataframe, plus number of months, to compare with current calendar month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

A column in dataframe looks like month, I want to use it to plus a month, as a 'future' month, then to compare this 'future' month with current (calendar) month.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

csvfile = StringIO(
"""Name Year - Month    Score
Mike    2022-11 31
Mike    2022-09 136
""")
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

d_name_plus_month = {"Mike":2}

month_of_first_row = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[[0]]['Year - Month']).values.astype("datetime64[M]")

plus_months = d_name_plus_month['Mike']

scheduled_month = month_of_first_row + int(plus_months)
# scheduled_month_in_string = scheduled_month.astype('str')

current_month = datetime.now().strftime("%Y") +'-' +datetime.now().strftime("%m")        # it's string
current_month = np.array(current_month)

print (scheduled_month <=  current_month)

# month_of_first_row: 2022-11
# scheduled_month: 2023-01
# current_month: 2023-02
# so "scheduled_month" is earlier than "current_month".
```

But it has error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I've tried to alert the lines to make them into string for compare, but not successful.

How can I correct the lines?

Comment: you df.shape is (2, 1), it is not good dataframe,  i can show code how to work pandas dataframe by datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use month periods by [`Serie.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for easy add/ remove months by integers:

```
d_name_plus_month = {"Mike":2}

month_of_first_row = pd.to_datetime(df['Year - Month'].iat[0]).to_period('m')
print (month_of_first_row)
2022-11

plus_months = d_name_plus_month['Mike']
scheduled_month = month_of_first_row + int(plus_months)

current_month = pd.Timestamp.now().to_period('m')
print (current_month)
2023-02

print (scheduled_month <=  current_month)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both `scheduled_month` and `current_month` to strings before comparison

```
scheduled_month_str = scheduled_month.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(str)

current_month_str = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m")

print(scheduled_month_str <= current_month_str)
```

Comment: thank you! very clean and neat coding! just hope you don't mind I choose the other answer which was posted earlier and with more details. :)

Answer (score 1):

month_of_first_row is an array with one value, you can add a [0] to convert it to get a single datetime object

```py
month_of_first_row = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[[0]]['Year - Month']).values.astype("datetime64[M]")[0]
```

And then convert the current month to a datetime objetc as well instead of a numpy array

```py
# no: current_month = np.array(current_month)
current_month = pd.to_datetime(current_month) # yes
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like right now
current month is `np.array('2023-02', dtype='<U7')`
and scheduled month is `np.array(['2023-01'], dtype='datetime64[M]')`

using this row will bring them to the same type:

```
current_month =np.array([current_month], dtype='datetime64[M]')
```

which should solve the error.

full code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from io import StringIO
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime
    
    csvfile = StringIO(
    """Name,Year - Month,Score
    Mike,2022-11,31
    Mike,2022-09,136
    """)
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = ',', engine='python')
    
    d_name_plus_month = {"Mike":2}
    
    month_of_first_row = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[[0]]['Year - Month']).values.astype("datetime64[M]")
    
    plus_months = d_name_plus_month['Mike']
    
    scheduled_month = month_of_first_row + int(plus_months)
    # scheduled_month_in_string = scheduled_month.astype('str')
    
    current_month = datetime.now().strftime("%Y") +'-' +datetime.now().strftime("%m")        # it's string
    current_month =np.array([current_month], dtype='datetime64[M]')

    print (scheduled_month <=  current_month)
```